# scatter plot coordinate data using Basemap, Python,

Tags: python, python-3.x, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap, scatter

I am a new python user and I need to plot the locations of satellite date of water vapor by using the Basemap (to just indicate where the data are available over the map, not plotting the value).

The nc file can be downloaded here:
https://ghrc.nsstc.nasa.gov/opendap/ssmis/f17/3day/data/2017/f17_ssmis_20170102v7_d3d.nc.html

my problem is that I don't know how to use the third column of values to show on which lat and lon data is available.

I really appreciate if some of you can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which data set are you using ascii, json?

Comment: I use netcdf format of atmosphere_water_vapor_content data set, and I convert the data set to a excel file which include three column of data of lat, lon, and values of water vapor data. my problem is that the third column includes values and NAN data, and I dont know how to assign the third column data to the coordinate columns